# install peer.js in vite with Vue 3 Typescript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite, peer

I'm using Vue 3 Typescript with Vite.js I want to install library [peer.js](https://peerjs.com/).
When I try using `Peer`:

```
import Peer from 'peerjs'
const myPeer = new Peer()
```

then Vite return error:

> ReferenceError: parcelRequire is not defined

How I can install Peer.js in Vite?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it's correct answer, but I added:

```
<script>
    var parcelRequire;
</script>
```

in `index.html` file

['parcelRequire is not defined' When used with snowpack. (Github)](https://github.com/peers/peerjs/issues/753#issuecomment-734757083)